# iOS - Dismiss RootViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview

I have a code like this to present a TOWebViewController that contain URL to my company web page.

```
TOWebViewController *webViewController = [[TOWebViewController alloc] initWithURL:url];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:webViewController];
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setRootViewController:navigationController];
```

After its open how I get back to my previous view or dismiss the root view controller since my navigator bar only show grey bar.

thanks

Comment: Why not use push/present

Comment: I don't understand why you use a webpage as your root view.It's a bad user experience.

Comment: @Vincent, the reason i use rootviewcontroller because in my webview i try to load imagepicker and i always got issue " Attempt to present <UIImagePickerController: 0x7fcf54932e00> on <UINavigationController: 0x7fcf538e0c00> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!" 
I use this to present it: [self.navigationController presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:NULL];

Comment: I can not see your code, but I think your code must be a problem.

Comment: Your app will almost sure to be declined because the root view is web view...u can always use uiimageview to get picture from url instead use webview if thats what u need

Answer (score 0):

Use `[self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];` instead.And don't use root view controller!

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a custom `back button @selector` and in it you need to set `[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setRootViewController:previousViewController];`
though you need the reference of your previous `viewController`, however i won't recommend this approach.As @lumialxk said, use this instead `[self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];`